# Powershell get-mailboxfolderstatistics multiple folders

Tags: powershell, scripting, exchange-server, powershell-2.0

I have this script. Looking to include, deleted items, sent items and drafts in the output.

Whats the best way to include that?

Thanks

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics myuserename -FolderScope Inbox | Where {$_.FolderPath -eq "/Inbox"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get-mailboxfolderstatistics myusername | where {$_.name -match "Inbox|Deleted|Sent|Calendar|Drafts"} |  sort-object Name | ft Name, FolderPath, ItemsInFolder, FolderSize -auto

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of is to filter multiple folders at once is to use -match and a regex alternation:

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics myuserename |
 Where {$_.FolderPath -match  '/Inbox|/Deleted Items|/Sent Items|/Drafts'}
```